# Why doesn't Firefox autofill forms any more?

Tags: firefox, auto-form-fill

Recently I realize that Firefox no longer remembers or fills web forms

I've never changed anything related to form autofill, and in *Privacy & Security* settings the option to [remember search and form history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/control-whether-firefox-automatically-fills-forms) is still checked. But there's no [Forms and Autofill section](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/automatically-fill-your-address-web-forms) in that page. I don't know since when that section has disappeared. I've also checked the `autofill` options in `about:config` and see nothing strange except `signon.autofillForms.autocompleteOff` is true. But turning it on does nothing, my names, phone numbers, addresses I've typed in the form still doesn't show when pressing the <kbd>Down</kbd> button

How to fix this so that Firefox can remember forms and autofill again?

- Firefox version 103.0.1 on Windows 11
- Firefox version 103.0 on Pop!_OS 22.04

Answer (score 0):

#### How to fix this so that Firefox can remember forms and autofill again?

> - Click menu button and select "Settings".
> - Select "Privacy & Security".
> - Select "Use custom settings for history" in the drop down under "History"
> - Enable "Remember search and form history".
> - Close the about:preferences page.

Source: [Firefox doesn't save web form entries](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-doesnt-save-web-form-entries)

[image]

Comment: I already checked that. The "Remember search and form history" has never been turned off. The setting is always at remember all

Comment: What about clear history? If that is enabled it will delete the form history.

Comment: The clear history button is to clear the history and not a checkbox

Comment: See my screen shot - it's a check box.

Comment: Nope, all the history has always been remembered